# Passing the document object to a web worker

Tags: jquery, html, web-worker

I know that web workers cant access the dom directly. But would it be a bad idea to do something like this:

```
var doc = $(document);

var worker = new Worker("worker.js");

worker.postMessage({ cmd: 'doDomStuff', data: doc });
```

Do you see any downsides with this peice of code?

Any tips/comments are much appreciated.

**update:** Just to be clear: I only want to getdata from the DOM, not set any new values or manipulate the DOM in any way.

Comment: In other languages, the only thread to manipulate the UI is the thread that created it (I'm thinking specifically .Net, but Java and others might do this too). Unless the browsers handle things differently, this is probably why web workers don't naturally have access to the DOM.

Comment: Sounds like something easy enough to test.

Comment: Send the data you need in the message

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<strike>I don't see any reason why you **can't** do this, but this could lead to issues when you are trying to manipulate the same element in the worker and in the main js code at the same time.</strike>

You would need to add some mutex locking to your code.

Sorry scratch the above...

---

> Workers do **NOT** have access to:
>
> The DOM (it's not thread-safe)
> The window object
> The document object
> The parent object

[**Source**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-enviornment-features)

Comment: I know that the worker doesnt have direct access to the DOM, thats why im trying to pass it as an object. I forgot to mention that i didnt intend to manipulate it in the worker. I just want to get values, not set anything.

Comment: @Johan it cant do **anything** to the dom. anything from the dom that you pass it will basically be a clone  of the object and you won't be able to do anything with it....

Comment: @Johan Most DOM properties are like getters, not static properties. A copy wouldn't have anything to 'get.' Also copying the entire document object for convenience if it were possible would be a little stinky unless you were hitting the vast majority of properties in it.